pip install error on Lambda function on Cloud9
I am trying to run this command on the bash console of AWS Cloud9.
pip3 install google-generativeai --target .
But I get the following error
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
botocore 1.34.95 requires urllib3<1.27,>=1.25.4; python_version < "3.10", but you have urllib3 2.2.1 which is incompatible.
awscli 2.14.5 requires urllib3<1.27,>=1.25.4, but you have urllib3 2.2.1 which is incompatible.

What causes the problem and what should I do?
